# No property getMaterials found for type Material! and Error creating bean with name 'materialRepository':

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster

I am getting a lot of errors that to be quite honest I do not understand. First I used JHipster to create this app. Very useful piece of opensource technology but it is doing a few things I am not familiar with.

I am simply trying to insert values into a database via JPA.

```
/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the Material entity.
 */
public interface MaterialRepository extends JpaRepository<Material,Long> {

     public void uploadMaterialData(String material_number, BigDecimal material_thickness,String material_size,BigDecimal lb_per_sheet,BigDecimal dollar_per_lb);

     List<Material> getMaterials(BigDecimal material_number);

}
```

small piece of the MaterialResource.java however it has `.save`

```
if (cit.hasNext()) {
                cell = cit.next();
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                String dollar_per_lb = cell.getStringCellValue();
                Double perLb_as_double = Double.parseDouble(dollar_per_lb);
                //now the conversion into big decimal happens
                BigDecimal dollar_per_lb_as_BigDecimal = new  
                BigDecimal(perLb_as_double,MathContext.DECIMAL64);
                this.dollar_per_lb = dollar_per_lb_as_BigDecimal;
                material.setDollar_per_lb(dollar_per_lb_as_BigDecimal);
            }

            Long materialValue =  
            Long.parseLong(material.getMaterial_number());

            //puts materials into map and the key is the material number
            materialMap.put(materialValue, material);

            materialRepository.save(material);
        }

        workbook.close();
```

Material.java

```
public class Material implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private Long id;

@Column(name = "material_number")
private String material_number;

@Column(name = "material_thickness", precision=10, scale=2)
private BigDecimal material_thickness;

@Column(name = "material_size")
private String material_size;

@Column(name = "lb_per_sheet", precision=10, scale=2)
private BigDecimal lb_per_sheet;

@Column(name = "dollar_per_lb", precision=10, scale=2)
private BigDecimal dollar_per_lb;

@Column(name = "inventory_count")
private Integer inventory_count;

....getter and setter methods below
```

ApplicationWebXml.java

```
/**
 * This is a helper Java class that provides an alternative to creating a   
web.xml.
*/
public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationWebXml.class);

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.profiles(addDefaultProfile())
            .showBanner(false)
            .sources(Application.class);
}

/**
 * Set a default profile if it has not been set.
 * <p/>
 * <p>
 * Please use -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
 * </p>
 */
private String addDefaultProfile() {
    String profile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
    if (profile != null) {
        log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", profile);
        return profile;
    }

    log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default    
configuration");
    return Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT;
}
}
```

Application.java

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

@Inject
private Environment env;

/**
 * Initializes hillcrestToolDie.
 * <p/>
 * Spring profiles can be configured with a program arguments --spring.profiles.active=your-active-profile
 * <p/>
 */
@PostConstruct
public void initApplication() throws IOException {
    if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
        log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
    } else {
        log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    }
}

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);

        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);

        // Check if the selected profile has been set as argument.
        // if not the development profile will be added
        addDefaultProfile(app, source);
        addLiquibaseScanPackages();
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        log.info("Access URLs:\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
            "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:{}\n\t" +
            "External: \thttp://{}:{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("server.port"),
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
            env.getProperty("server.port"));

    }

    /**
     * Set a default profile if it has not been set
     */
    private static void addDefaultProfile(SpringApplication app, SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source) {
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active")) {
            app.setAdditionalProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the liquibases.scan.packages to avoid an exception from ServiceLocator.
     */
    private static void addLiquibaseScanPackages() {
        System.setProperty("liquibase.scan.packages", Joiner.on(",").join(
            "liquibase.change", "liquibase.database", "liquibase.parser",
            "liquibase.precondition", "liquibase.datatype",
            "liquibase.serializer", "liquibase.sqlgenerator", "liquibase.executor",
            "liquibase.snapshot", "liquibase.logging", "liquibase.diff",
            "liquibase.structure", "liquibase.structurecompare", "liquibase.lockservice",
            "liquibase.ext", "liquibase.changelog"));
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'materialResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.htd.repository.MaterialRepository com.htd.web.rest.MaterialResource.materialRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'materialRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getMaterials found for type Material!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at com.htd.Application.main(Application.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.htd.repository.MaterialRepository com.htd.web.rest.MaterialResource.materialRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'materialRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getMaterials found for type Material!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'materialRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getMaterials found for type Material!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getMaterials found for type Material!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:349)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: I suppose you did not autowire the Material bean in your configuration xml

Comment: That the crazy thing, there is not a configuration.xml file in this JHipster created application.

Answer (score 3):

Spring data holds a mechanism by which a query is resolved based on the method name, from the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

> The query builder mechanism built into Spring Data repository
> infrastructure is useful for building constraining queries over
> entities of the repository. The mechanism strips the prefixes find…By,
> read…By, query…By, count…By, and get…

so when the `get` is stripped from your `List<Material> getMaterials(BigDecimal material_number);` it attempts on searching the property named `materials` against the `Material` entity.

As it appears, you don't want to automatically resolve the query for that particular method, so you can simply change the name, so that the query derivation mechanism does not kick in e.g. `List<Material> retrieveMaterials(BigDecimal material_number);`

Comment: can we chat? I am pretty sure by reading your post you can solve my issue and I do not want a bunch of run on comments on this post.

Comment: we can try, but I have only few mins available

Comment: I never have used chat on here, I'll figure it out. My question is: What about `void uploadMaterialData` I used the `@Query` annotation and that did not work either. I read the same doc you posted but it seems I just keep hitting walls.

Comment: well, depends on what is failing. You should post the problem you're facing with it, but its a separate issue, so you would get better feedback if you post it as a separate one. The docs that explain and provide some examples are available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)